# Suppress dialog box for a dropped shape in Visio VBA

Tags: vba, visio

When I drop a milestone from the shape master onto a page, a dialog pops up asking for data (milestone date, description, etc.). How can I prevent this dialog box? I set the values in code.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I prevent this dialog box?

**IMHO** No way ! Because this dialog box managed by build-in add-ons (aka wizards) like **Project Timeline**, **Gantt Chart** and so on…